# post loop values in a variable (functions.php)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

So, I have the following post loop to show posts (wp functions.php).

```
global $post;    
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',      
    'posts_per_page' => 3,  
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$id = get_the_ID();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

$my_post['sample_id'] =  get_the_title( $id );  

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I need to have the title of posts in an array of values (for example array[title1, title2, title3]).

However, it only picks up one title.

How do I make it so that the `$my_post` variable can have three values?

**(In other words, I simply want to have three titles as a result in a variable)**

**EDIT:**

```
....
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();   
array_push($titleArray, get_the_title($id));    
endwhile;
$tag_post['sample_id'] =  $titleArray;  
echo json_encode($tag_post);
wp_reset_postdata();
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`wp_list_puck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

You can try the following

```
$args = [
    // Your arguments
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
$titles = wp_list_pluck( $q, 'post_title' );
var_dump( $titles );
```

Comment: I am interested to use this. I will give it a try! =) Thanks Pieter

Comment: No problem, this method is faster than what you have so you should really consider it ;-)

Comment: I read the documentation! =) Thank you Pieter. I am implementing this method as it only does what I need to do.

Comment: `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query`,  The big difference is that `get_posts()` passes `'no_found_rows' => true` to `WP_Query` which skips pagination. This makes the query much faster. This is also why `get_posts()` should not be used for paginated queries. For all non-paginated queries, I just use `get_posts()`.

Comment: I see. =) Thank you Pieter! I read lots of your answers throughout the site and  oh man, you know a lot of wp materials. haha. Once again, appreciate your help!

Comment: If you use a current PHP version, you might also try [`array_column`](http://php.net/en/array_column).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code to store all titles into an array,

```
global $post;    
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',      
    'posts_per_page' => 3,  
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $titleArray[] = get_the_title();
endwhile; 

print_r($titleArray); // Store to a variable as per your needs
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added an edit version. I am getting `null` as a result. Does my edit version look alright? thanks

Comment: @steveKim Your updated code works fine for me, here is the ouput: {"sample_id":["post1","post2","post3"]}

Comment: Can you specify the hook which you are using in functions to php to render this code?

Comment: Perfect. It is working ! =) Thank you. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**for instance:**

```
<?php 
global $post;
global $all_post_titles; //possibly needed//
$all_post_titles = array();
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',      
    'posts_per_page' => 3,  
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); $all_post_titles[] = the_title('','',false); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**and:**

```
<?php 
  global $all_post_titles; //possibly needed//
  echo my_get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $taxonomy,  '', ' ', '', $all_post_titles );
?>
```

depending where the second code is, you might not need to declare `$all_post_titles` as a global variable.

If you want all post data into array then this code will help you.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post'));
$posts = $query->get_posts();
$postArray = array();
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // Do your stuff, e.g.
    // $postArray[] = $post->post_name;
    // store data to array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to simply get the data and save them in a variable? I made an edit to my original post.

Comment: Thank you! I was also able to make it work with your answer! =) Really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do nothing you have to just change your one line in your code.

Replace it

```
$my_post['sample_id'] =  get_the_title( $id );
```

With it:

```
$my_post['title'][] =  get_the_title( );  // $my_post will be your array containing all titles of your post.
```

$my_post[] will act like **array_push** there.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I need to specify the data name to use it in frontend. I do get the data, but I am only getting one value.

Comment: then just use multidimensial array just replace $my_post[] with $my_post['title'][]